# How to resolve "DNS Zone does not have enough labels via PowerShell" error

Tags: azure, powershell, dns

I am trying to Create a Private DNS zone by specifying virtual network IDs with [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.dns/new-azdnszone?view=azps-3.1.0), and my command goes as follows,

```
New-AzDnsZone -Name 'dnszone01' -ResourceGroupName 'thisRG' -ZoneType 'Private' -RegistrationVirtualNetworkId @($vnet.Id)
```

I am getting an error as,

> New-AzDnsZone : The zone name 'dnszone01' does not have enough labels.
>   Zone names must have two or more labels. At line:1 char:1
>   + New-AzDnsZone -Name 'dnszone01' -ResourceGroupName 'thisRG' -Zon ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzDnsZone], CloudException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Dns.NewAzureDnsZone

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The dns name must be fully qualifed. for example:

- dnszone1.local
- dnszone.mysite.com

Answer (score 1):

Add `.azure.com` to the name:
**Example** -

```
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "dnszone" {
 name = "${var.private_dns_zone_name}-pdz.postgres.database.azure.com"
 resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
```